# PHP namespace reachability

Tags: php, file, hierarchy

Why I cant reach a const like this? How can i reach it?

**index.php:**

```
namespace core;

const CONSTANT = 1;

include_once("lib/somefile.php");

/*------------------------*/
```

**lib/somefile.php:**

```
namespace core\lib;

echo CONSTANT; /*doesn't work */
echo core\CONSTANT; /* doesn't work either */
```

Comment: `echo \core\CONSTANT` ?

Comment: So this question is over? Consider removing it

Comment: @DamienPirsy youre right, i have to add a \ to the begining, to clearify that tis is from global. Would you post this?

Answer (score 2):

Use `echo \core\CONSTANT;`

`core\CONSTANT` would look into the same namespace (`core\lib`), as it would work with filesystems, it would load `\core\lib\core\CONSTANT` , which is the wrong namespace path.

You need to look starting from the root namespace (`\`) and, following the same rule as filesystem paths.

Answer (score 1):

**index.php:**

```
namespace core;

const CONSTANT = 1;

include_once("lib/somefile.php");

/*------------------------*/
```

**lib/somefile.php:**

```
namespace core\lib;

use core;

echo core\CONSTANT; /* works*/
```

You have to use the `use` keyword, to interact with other namespaces.

As Damien Pirsy mentioned, you can also write a `\` in front of the echo, to clarify that this constant is from the global namespace:

```
namespace core\lib;

echo \core\CONSTANT; /* works*/
```